# Should we expect to see Tor Hidden Services get load balancing (similar to I2P's and multi-homing feature) in the next several years?

Tags: onion-services, load-balance

I realize this question would be highly subject to unknown variables, but I have to presume a few devs are at least partially interested in onion features and someone might have an idea where load balancing (similar to I2P's multi-homing) might fall in their priorities when it comes to working on Tor Hidden Service features.

Comment: See http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13/can-a-hidden-service-be-hosted-by-multiple-instances-of-tor for related comments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
I imagine there will be quite a few improvements made to hidden services in the coming years.
In fact I think work is currently being done on exactly what you're describing.
[Draft proposal for scalable Hidden Services](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2013-October/005674.html)