# I want to host multiple hidden services on my apache

Tags: onion-services

```
HiddenServiceDir /home/username/hiddenservice19/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

HiddenServiceDir /home/username/hiddenservice18/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:67
```

After restarting Tor it creates those 2 files, I get my onion address and I can see 1 site.

In this case the hiddenservice19 and it displays my index.html file just fine.

Why hiddenservice18 does not work??

My index.html file is in following folder
/var/www/html/index.html

Where do I have to put file hiddenservice2.html so it can be shown at the onion address for hiddenservice18 ??

Comment: There is a practical limit to how many hidden services maybe running in a single Tor instance.
For more information on this limit, please look at this Q&A and its associated links. https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/1000s-of-hidden-services

Comment: Have you set up logging? If yes, do you see any errors or warnings?

Comment: first of all, running hidden services and non-Tor websites on the same server is
generally considered bad practice.
second: did you configure your webserver to listen on port 67? you can only redirect the tor service connection to an open port, where some service is listening...

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. As there was no activity for more than half a year, I'll close this question. @jones and others: Feel free to add more information so that we can reopen and answer it.

Answer (score -1):

In your question, you did not provide clear information about how many hidden services you wish to run in a given Tor instance, plus you did not provide any information about your CPU, the OS and the browser you are using, all of the above information have relevence to the answer you get. However, I will provide some general information, but, If you provide the necessary information, the answer may get more customized to your specific situation.

There is a practical limit to how many hidden sevices can be run in a single Tor instance. This limit depend on many things. The items below do not mean to be an exhaustive list of all possible causes of the problem, but may point you to the right direction:

1. Your CPU computation capability is limited. Depending on what type of CPU you use, sooner or later you reach your CPU computation limitation. For example if you have a slow, low power type CPU, you will reach this limitation very soon.
2. The OS and the browser you are running also could limit your capability sooner or later.
3. The number of hidden sevices have an effect on number of relays you need to employee to handle the situation. There is a limit to number of relays you may use concurrently.
4. There is also a possibility that you are doing something wrong.

If you provide your log and additional information one can diagnose your problem more accurately.

Answer (score -1):

You do not to use two different ports to host 2 different hidden services, which in your case didn't work because your webserver is configured to listen only on port 80.

The better approach is to make your webserver handle the different hidden services. In case your webserver is Apache for instance, you can [configure different virtualhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html), each with a `ServerName` equal to the corresponding onion address and `DocumentRoot` corresponding to the public html folder of the hidden site.