# Can I have more than one .onion site?

Tags: onion-routing

Is it possible to create more than one .onion site on one computer? I know that it involves using my server so it would be weird if I could but if I can could you please tell me how or lead me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [page on configuring hidden services](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en), specifically [step three](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en#three), which deals with more advanced options.

If you want to run lots of hidden services on a single box, this thread might be of interest:

[How many hidden services can I run on a single Tor instance?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-many-hidden-services-can-i-run-on-a-single-tor-instance)

Comment: So I followed the instructions on the first link you sent but how do I edit my server so that it will listen to all of the servers? I cant figure that part out

Comment: I've replied to your separate question about this. http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7331/how-do-i-host-multiple-hidden-services-in-my-server