# How do I host multiple hidden services in my server?

Tags: onion-services, server

I know that to create more sites in Tor I add `HiddenServiceDir` and `HiddenServicePort` to my `etc/tor/torrc` file but how do I edit it in my server to listen to all of them and do I need to create new `index.html` files for the other sites?

I am using Nginx on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `server` entry in your Nginx config file for each service. For example, with two hidden services your config file might look something like:

```
server {
    listen   127.0.0.1:<port_hidden_service_1>;

    root /path/to/hidden_service_1/;
    index_1 index_1.html index_1.htm;

    server_name domain_1.onion;
}

server {
    listen   127.0.0.1:<port_hidden_service_2>;

    root /path/to/hidden_service_2/;
    index_2 index_2.html index_2.htm;

    server_name domain_2.onion;
}
```

You might have some additional config fields in there, but you get the idea.

For reference, see the Nginx [server name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) config documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I do this and create 3 different sites, I am unable to connect to any of them through the tor browser or localhost on a normal internet. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Did you originally manage to get a single hidden service to work, before you added the others?

Comment: Yes, I was able to get to my site through the localhost and the tor browser