# How to use HAProxy/OnionBalance to create a high availability load balancer for tor hidden service?

Tags: onion-services, server-administration

I have gone through this question [SO](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13/can-a-hidden-service-be-hosted-by-multiple-instances-of-tor?newreg=8008f12d747e497a9a37a742eaac6a6e) but the solution suggested as [OnionBalance](https://onionbalance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or other HAProxy options will result in a single point of failure - either the loadbalancer or else the server running the OnionBalancer.

Is there a possible way of creating a high availability setup (the way it is done in the DNS world using a floating or private ip setup and creating active/passive cluster)?

Comment: Can you clarify where you think the "single point of failure" is? There are n systems running Tor and hosting the onion services and one system that's republishing a super-descriptor of all of their introduction points. The one publishing the super-descriptor is just publishing the others, it doesn't handle the requests, they get distributed between the IPs in the super-descriptor? See: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/cooking-onions-finding-onionbalance

Answer (score 0):

nope, sadly: you can not run multiple HS instances of your website in current Tor base(in my patch it's possible, but it will be released later after a proper debugging). If your HS website is static(=does not require a database and/or active server environment like PHP) - use [ZeroNET](https://zeronet.io/), it does exactly what you need.

Comment: You can infact run multiple HS instances of your website, as per the OnionBalance document in the question.

Comment: yes, *physically* you can, but looking at the diagram [here](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/cooking-onions-finding-onionbalance) you will see that this is counter-productive and it's not a cluster at all

Comment: The architecture for the multiple servers on the back-end is arbitrary, which you'd know if you understood the concept.

Comment: @canonizingironize the problem is defenately **not** a back-end: it's arbitrary to have a complementary backend in case of *any* load ballancing. The problem is that resulting descriptor will **NOT** provide a true load ballancing in case of 5-10 nodes. Take a deep look at the diagram and the description. The problem is a double-fork: either you have a very long descriptors or you will have NO true ballancing via limited descriptors. A change of protocol and the paradigm is required to fulfill the purpose of load-ballancing. In my patch I left this topic behind for now:the question is TOO deep